# Hibernate + Karaf: how to register my entity?

Tags: hibernate, osgi, karaf

I get an exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : entity.CategoryEntity

even though I exported package in my manifest file, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you include persistence.xml into bundle with Meta-Persistence manifest header?

Comment: @DmytroPishchukhin no, started reading your article